# iPhone Ad Hoc Failure

Tags: iphone, ad-hoc-distribution, ios5

I am distributing an iPhone app to beta testers, some of whom (with iPhone 4 or 4s, iOS 5.0.1) have reported that the provisioning profile loads fine, they see the standard `"installing"` progress bar on the screen of the phone, and then, just before the installation is complete, they receive an error on the phone stating

`"(Name of app) failed to install"`

I'm using XCode 4.2.1.  My phone is running 5.0.1 on an iPhone 4s myself, and I have no problems loading the app via Ad Hoc installation.

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?  Does this indicate that there's some problem with the provisioning profile?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't signed the distribution for their devices. It's not enough to have them install the profile. Ad hoc's have to include every UDID they are going to run on.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but all user's UDIDs are included in the provisioning profile.  I'll have them resend to be sure.

Comment: Double check that you've added them in the provisioning profile and that you've redownloaded the profile and readded it to Xcode. It can be pretty easy to use an out of date profile in Xcode.